# C++ pass by reference returning junk or in wrong variable

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, cimg

I'm pulling pixel data from an image using the CImg library and placing it in an array in a struct:

```
int JpgHandle::loadJpg(const char* Name, SImageData & data){

    CImg<unsigned long> src(Name);
    int width = src.width();
    int height = src.height();
    unsigned long * pixels = new unsigned long [width*height];
    for (int r = 0; r < height; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < width; c++){
            unsigned long pixel = (src(c,r,0,2) ) |
                                  (src(c,r,0,1) <<  8) |
                                  (src(c,r,0,0) << 16);
            *(pixels++) = pixel;
        }
    }

    data.pData = pixels;
    data.lWidth = (long) width;
    data.lHeight = (long) height;
    data.lStride = (long) width;

    return 1;
}
```

SImageData is defined thus:

```
struct SImageData {
    unsigned long *pData;
    long lWidth;
    long lHeight;
    long lStride;

    SImageData() : pData(NULL), lWidth(0), lHeight(0), lStride(0) {}
};
```

When I call loadJpg from main like this:

```
JpgHandle handler;
SImageData data1;

handler.loadJpg(argv[1], data1);

cout << "data1: ";
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << hex << data1.pData[i] << ", ";
}
cout << "\n";
```

It returns junk:

```
data1: 0, 1eff1, 7f226014e798, 7f226014e798, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

However, if I do this in main:

```
JpgHandle handler;
SImageData data1;
SImageData data2;

handler.loadJpg(argv[1], data1);
handler.loadJpg(argv[2], data2);

cout << "data1: ";
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << hex << data1.pData[i] << ", ";
}
cout << "\n";

cout << "data2: ";
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << hex << data2.pData[i] << ", ";
}
cout << "\n";
```

The result is that data1 contains the data from argv[2] and data2 contains junk:

```
data1: 0, 2011, a0a0a, a0a0a, a0a0a, 90909, 90909, a0a0a, b0b0b, b0b0b, 
data2: 0, 7f0d7d712798, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

What gives?

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour They are paths to jpg photos.

Comment: You are incrementing the `pixels` pointer inside those nested loops so it no longer points to the start of the allocated memory block when you assign it to `data.pData`.

Comment: Ah, I see, so I have to have a pointer pointing to the start of that array so I can pass that to data.pData?

Comment: For a total hack you can just `data.pData = pixels - (width*height);` , or `unsigned long *pixels = data.pData = new unsigned long [width*height];` and forego the assignment after the loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the pointer to allocated memory into `data.pData` **before** you enter the nested loops. The loops increment `pixels` so it no longer points the the start of the memory block.

Do you ever call `delete[]` on `data.pData`? That should have triggered a fault because it wasn't the same address returned from `new[]`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem. No I'm not calling delete[], but it didn't give any runtime errors.

Comment: @omnipotato: The bad pointer also meant you were accessing memory outside the allocated block. You just got unlucky that it didn't fail in an obvious way.

Comment: @omnipotato leak memory enough times, I assure you  you'll have plenty of runtime errors. Clean up properly, or better still, use a `std::vector<unsigned long>` and let it do all the housekeeping for you. (and +1, Mr Furnace =P)

Comment: I'm using someone else's code that takes a pointer to a unsigned long array, or else I probably would.

Comment: @omnipotato their API takes an `unsigned long*` ? You can *still* use a `std::vector<unsigned long>`. Pass the [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member result to the API requiring the pointer (assuming you properly sized and filled your  vector, of course).